# Is it possible to use “have” in this case?

Tags: word-usage

I know it is acceptable to use the verb *get* when saying you are trying to get yourself to do something or you are trying to make yourself do something

Examples:

- After much hesitation I finally got myself to enter the dark room.= Even with difficulty the speaker succeeded in convincing himself to enter the room.
- Despite being extremely lazy as I was, I made myself get up.=The speaker forced himself to get up.

But is it possible to use the verb *have* in this way too?

Example:

- I need to have myself standing at the door, when the guests come in.
- I need to have myself ready for the meeting.
- I want to have myself see the painting.

All of the last three sentences sound very odd if not utterly wrong to me, so are they?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. These sentences are extremely awkward, because they are verbose. I think they can be rewritten like this and still convey the same feeling of "getting yourself to do something":

- I need to be standing in front of the door when the guests come in.
- I need to be ready for the meeting
- I want to see the painting.

I'm not sure if the originals are grammatically incorrect or just poorly constructed... Either way I wouldn't use them.

This question is really interesting!! I really hope someone with more expertise can give us a clear explanation.